# Regex expression for exactly known pattern without "cutting into" the string not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently developing a web-application where I work with java, javascript, html, jquery, etc. and at some point I need to check that whether an input matches a known pattern and only proceed if it is true.

The pattern should be [at least one but max 3 numbers between 0-9]/[exactly 4 numbers between 0-9], so the only acceptable variations should be like

`1/2014` or `23/2015` or `123/2016`.

and nothing else, and I CANNOT accept something like `1234/3012` or anything else, and this is my problem right here, it accepts everything in which it can find the above pattern, so like from `12345/6789` it accepts and saves `345/6789`.

I am a total newbie with regex, so I checked out http://regexr.com and this is the code I have in my javascript:

```
$.validator.addMethod("hatarozat", function(value, element) {
        return (this.optional(element) || /[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/)[0-9]{4}/i.test(value));
    }, "Hibás határozat szám!");
```

So this is my regex: `/[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/)[0-9]{4}/i`
which I built up using the above website. What could be the problem, or how can I achived what I described? I tried `/^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/)[0-9]{4}$/i`but this doesn't seem to work, please anyone help me, I have everything else done and am getting pretty stressed over something looking so simple yet I cannot solve it. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `/^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/)[0-9]{4}$/` *does not work*? See https://regex101.com/r/Qrg5mC/1. I think this regex is working well. Check  `this.optional(element)` - try removing this condition.

Comment: Are you Hungarian too?

Comment: I mean that the problem remains, it still doesn't show an error when it should, the only change is that the whole document seems to disappear after I save it, so probably it sees that something is not right, but doesn'tshow the error. Here is the rest of my code in connection with this: $("form[name='hataskormuveletform']").validate({
    errorClass : "my-error-class",   
    rules: {
        hatarozat: { hatarozat: true, required: true, hatnev : true},
        datum: { required: true },
        eloterjeszto: { required: true },
        targy: { required: true, maxlength: 256}
       },

Comment: Please remove `this.optional(element) ||` and retry  with `return /^[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{4}$/.test(value);` (add `^` at the start and `$` at the end). Add all the relevant code to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: and yes I am hungarian too :D

Comment: okay, thanks i will try this now, and  this is my first question, sorry for the inapproptiate form :D

Comment: @DoraJurievnaDusyn: Does that work or is there anything else to account for? Should an empty string match, too?

Comment: Yes, this seems to work now, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last regex with the anchors (`^` and `$`) is a correct regex. What prevents your code from working is `this.optional(element) ||`. Since this is a static thing, and is probably true, so it does not show any error (as `||` is an OR condition, if the first is true, the whole returns true, the regex is not checked at all).

So, use

```
return /^[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{4}$/.test(value);
```

Note you do not need the `(?:...)` with `\/` as the grouping does not do anything important here and is just redundant. The anchors are important, since you want the whole string to match the pattern (and `^` anchors the regex at the start of the string and `$` does that at the end of the string.)

Answer (score 0):

You need use the the following special characters in your regex expression: 
`^` and `$`
or `\b`

so 2 regexp will be correct:

```
/\b[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/)[0-9]{4}\b/i;
```

or

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\/)[0-9]{4}$/i
```